# Cordova FileTranfer plugin currupts image after uploading

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I want to upload JPG file using Cordova org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FiletTansfer Plugin. It successfully upload the image to the specified server but the image lost its quality and get corrupted. My JavaScript code looks like:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

params.value1 = "image";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(serviceURL+"upload_ipad.php"), uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options);
```

Where uploadSuccess and uploadFail are my JavaScript functions that are called accordingly on file upload success or failure respectively.

After upload my Image looks as shown in screen shot.Can anybody helps me what I am missing or doing not correctly. Thanks

[image]